# Why Does it take 30+ seconds to list the contents of the Download directory?

Tags: windows-10

Windows-10 64 bit with an SSD. C:\Users\User\Downloads contains:

- 521 Files
- 14 folders
- 10.8 GB Size on disk

Why does Windows Explorer take 30+ seconds to read and list the contents of the directory?  In previous versions of Windows with spinning hard drives, this nearly instantaneous.  I ask because if it is a simple setting to change, I would like to do so.

Comment: Are you talking about "listing" files with Windows Explorer on Windows 10 ?

Comment: Related? http://superuser.com/questions/501685/why-does-my-downloads-folder-take-so-long-to-load

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities:

1. There could be links or dependencies to a drive that has to spin up. Check this by moving half the files from *Downloads* to another folder, checking if that resolves the issue, and then reversing the folders in which the files reside, is there was no change. If it's a file issue, then you can narrow this down to particular files.
2. There might be large files, such as ISO images, that are being scanned by your antivirus. To test this, **temporarily** turn off just long enough to open *Downloads*, then reopen it.
3. **MS DRM** may be scanning files in *Downloads* and checking license to view them over the web. Temporarily move all media files to another directory to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Moving large ISO files to another has accelerated the process: I think that a Microsoft process was reading these files.  MS DRM does not apply because no media files are in the directory.  The 'move a class of files' and test the read-speed strategy is excellent.

Comment: "I think that a Microsoft process was reading these files." and I told you which Microsoft program ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused [by the Windows Defender](https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/case-of-the-slow-downloads-folder/) which scans all files before Windows can read them.

[image]

So avoid Windows Defender and install a 3rd party Anti Virus suite which scans files on write/execute and not during reading of Fileinfo (like icons, details which explorer needs to display in the Explorer view)