# Downloads folder taking forever

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In Windows Explorer, when I try to navigate to the Downloads folder, it takes forever to scan and display the contents - even when the folder is empty. Does anyone know what might cause this? It's a recent thing. Maybe due to other installed software.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/501685/605470

Comment: Andrew is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is caused by Microsoft Security Essentials / Defender](https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/case-of-the-slow-downloads-folder/).

The service scans the files randomly and causes a lot of disk IO and delays:

[image]

Remove MSE and try a different AV suite.