# Windows "Downloads" folder take an eternity to load

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

My Downloads folder takes several minutes to load every time, doesn't automatically refresh if files are added to it and if I do hit the Refresh button the process starts over. There are ~100 items in the folder at the moment but this happens when there are 1000s or dozens. Seems to be the case with whatever View I'm in (details, group by date...)

[image]

Like [these answers](https://superuser.com/a/501692/85273) suggest I've set the folder to optimize for "General Items" but it has no positive effect.

[image]

What gives? Why is this one folder so incapable of rendering its contents quickly?

Comment: Make a new, test Windows User Account and set up a test for Downloads in the new User Account. Your main User Profile may be damaged.

Comment: I'd be hesitant to add a new user account as this is a work computer. Is there another way to diagnose this?

Comment: If this is a work computer, ask your Company IT for help.

Comment: @John Maybe you haven't work for a large corporation before.... that's a bit of a non-starter.

Comment: Yes I have worked for very large corporations

Comment: @Brad - The solution to this problem involves deleting the user profile and profiles directory which can only be accomplished by an Administrator

Comment: I occassionally see a delay similar to when `This PC` is looking for a disconnected network drive. My ***guess*** is that it's related to some security process because of the increased risk downloaded files can pose. In the registry, `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}` is one of just a few folders that have a `Security` entry specifed. For `Downloads`, it's "S:AI(RA;IOOICI;;;;WD;("IMAGELOAD",TU,0x0,0x01))" --  standalone user here and not well-versed in security -- just an observation.

Comment: *"Maybe you haven't work for a large corporation before.... that's a bit of a non-starter."*  Honestly, that probably says as much about you as it does about your IT support staff.  I have managed rather large Windows domains for decades, and if one of my smarter end-users was presumptuous enough to bypass my team completely while asking for help on Super User, we would definitely have a 1-on-1 mentoring session afterwards.

Comment: @Run5k I'm honestly flabbergasted by such a response. This very easily could have had a simple answer like I need to reindex my profile or I need to not have mapped drives. If it turned out this is a common problem with an easy answer that I'm just not searching for then spending 6 hours explaining this to 8 different IT staff who are too busy dealing with people's actual work stopping issues instead of minor annoyances to care about something like this is a much better use of everyone's time.

Comment: *"I'm honestly flabbergasted by such a response."*  I'm sorry, but once again that says much more about you than anyone else.  It is your IT support staff's job to solve computer-related problems, both big and small.  It certainly shouldn't take you *that* much time to explain the problem to them and if it is as simple as you implied that it could be, they will solve it for you relatively quickly.  If it really is a bit more complicated than that, there is a good chance that you are not the first end-user on the domain to encounter that problem, and they have already determined the root cause.

Comment: @KeithMiller unfortunately I don't even have a `FolderDescriptions` node in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`

Comment: @Brad, it's under `HKLM`, and I wasn't suggesting editing or deletion, just posing a theory as to why `Downloads` behaves differently from other folders...

Comment: **Pro Tip**:  if you really are adamant about bypassing your imbedded IT support team to tackle this problem, rather than utilizing Super User it would probably be prudent to ask the Stack Exchange people who actually do perform enterprise-level computer support:  [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)